# Borrowing issues with attempted caching

Tags: rust

The following code snippet does the same things in 3 ways.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    cache: HashMap<String, String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_cached(&mut self, key: &String) -> &String {
        if !self.cache.contains_key(key) {
            self.cache.insert(key.clone(), String::from("default"));
        }
        self.cache.get(key).unwrap()
    }
    fn show_impl(&self, what: &String) {
        println!("{}", what);
    }
    pub fn show1(&mut self, key: &String) {
        println!("{}", self.get_cached(key));
    }
    pub fn show2(&mut self, key: &String) {
        if !self.cache.contains_key(key) {
            self.cache.insert(key.clone(), String::from("default"));
        }
        self.show_impl(self.cache.get(key).unwrap());
    }
    // This does not compile
    pub fn show3(&mut self, key: &String) {
        self.show_impl(self.get_cached(key));
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

`show3` doesn't compile, giving the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:28:24
   |
28 |         self.show_impl(self.get_cached(key));
   |         ----           ^^^^                - immutable borrow ends here
   |         |              |
   |         |              mutable borrow occurs here
   |         immutable borrow occurs here
```

As far as I tell, the issue with `show3` is not about mutability, but rather a double borrow: the borrow of `self` is given away to `get_cached` which doesn't end because `get_cached` returns a reference to something contained in `self`. Is this even correct?

How can I accomplish my intended goal of looking up a value in a mutable cache in self and pass the reference to another method of self?

Comment: I've added a new solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rust doesn't handle this sort of caching well at the moment.

The best solution is to avoid the problem altogether. Does `show_impl` really need to be a method of `Foo`? If not, you can define a new trait and implement it for `String`. For example:

```
trait ShowImpl: std::fmt::Display {
    fn show_impl(&self) {
        println!("{}", self);
    }
}

impl ShowImpl for String {}
```

Then just call `show_impl` on the string: `self.get_cached(key).show_impl();`

---

Here is a solution that uses `UnsafeCell`. I'm not sure if it works correctly. While it does compile, the use of unsafe code means the compiler can no longer guarantee safety.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;

struct Foo {
    cache: UnsafeCell<HashMap<String, String>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn get_cached(&self, key: &String) -> &String {
        unsafe {
            if !(*self.cache.get()).contains_key(key) {
                (*self.cache.get()).insert(key.clone(), String::from("default"));
            }
            (*self.cache.get()).get(key).unwrap()
        }
    }
    fn show_impl(&self, what: &String) {
        println!("{}", what);
    }
    pub fn show1(&mut self, key: &String) {
        println!("{}", self.get_cached(key));
    }
    pub fn show2(&mut self, key: &String) {
        unsafe {
            if !(*self.cache.get()).contains_key(key) {
                (*self.cache.get()).insert(key.clone(), String::from("default"));
            }
            self.show_impl((*self.cache.get()).get(key).unwrap());
        }
    }

    pub fn show3(&self, key: &String) {
        self.show_impl(self.get_cached(key));
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Comment: The code I posted is the simplest example I could find. In my actual use case `self` provides resources essential to handling the value retrieved from the cache. But it is useful to know that this is not well handled by rust yet. Makes it easier to move on and look for other ways to structure my code.

Comment: I guess `UnsafeCell` is overkill here; `RefCell` is more than enough.

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev I'm not 100% sure but I think RefCell doesn't work here because a reference to a value in the hash map needs to be returned.

Comment: I tried myself with RefCell only to quickly realize that exact problem. You solution is appreciated, and may be useful. Still, for now I'd rather not use unsafe code. My current workaround is to wrap the values of the map in Rc. Not the optimal solution performance wise, but at least I there will be no surprises.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: sometimes the simplest approach is best, performance may suffer, but optimizing for understanding and clarity has its own benefits! You might want to answer with the `Rc` approach by the way, I would certainly favor it over `unsafe` myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `&mut` on `self` on `show_impl` as in

```
...
fn show_impl(&self, what: &String)  
...
```

So it won't get mixed.

Comment: Mutability is not the issue. Making `show_impl` take `&mut self` gives a specific double borrowing error.