# How can I convince the borrow checker to allow me to cache values?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The borrow checker beat me:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cache {
    cache: Vec<HashMap<String, String>>,
}

impl Cache {
    fn get(&mut self, index: usize, key: String) -> String {
        let mut cache = &mut self.cache[index];
        match cache.get(&key) {
            Some(r) => {
                return r.clone();
            }
            None => {
                let r = "foo".to_string(); // something smart here
                cache.insert(key, r.clone());
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*cache` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:16:17
   |
10 |         match cache.get(&key) {
   |               ----- immutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |                 cache.insert(key, r.clone());
   |                 ^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
19 |         }
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

How can I rewrite my code so that it compiles?

Comment: I would think someone with almost 6k rep would format their question a bit better. "How can I rewrite my code so that it compiles" doesn't really target your specific problem (not understanding why you cannot borrow field as mutable while it's borrowed as immutable). Check out [this](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/12/two-bugs-in-the-borrow-checker-every-rust-developer-should-know-about/), scroll down to "*Borrow scopes should not always be lexical*", and read up. It explains why this error occurs and how to get around it

Comment: [Borrowing issues with attempted caching](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25190063/155423) may also provide insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is to use the `entry` interface. The only downside with this approach is that it (currently) doesn't use the `BorrowFrom` infrastructure that the `get` method uses, which makes it less flexible. In your case, that isn't a problem since `get` takes an owned key. The advantage of `entry` is that it only does one hash lookup, whereas using `get` forces you to do two lookups.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cache {
    cache: Vec<HashMap<String, String>>,
}

impl Cache {
    fn get(&mut self, index: usize, key: String) -> String {
        self.cache[index]
            .entry(key)
            .or_insert_with(|| "foo".to_string())
            .clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: "you have to clone the key" Are you sure? I don't see why the key can't be moved into the `entry()` call.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev You're absolutely right. I meant to say that `entry` doesn't have as flexible of an interface as `get`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: As I understand it, [Collections Reform Part 2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0509-collections-reform-part-2.md) should add the BorrowFrom infrastructure to `entry` as well.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I really like your decision, because HashMap lookup only happens once. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The borrow checker sees `cache.get` as an immutable borrow, despite the fact that it is returning `None`. The easiest way to change your code is to move the insert out of the match, e.g.:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Cache {
    cache: Vec<HashMap<String, String>>,
}

impl Cache {
    fn get(&mut self, index: usize, key: String) -> String {
        let mut cache = &mut self.cache[index];
        match cache.get(&key) {
            Some(r) => {
                return r.clone();
            }
            None => (),
        }
        let r = "foo".to_string(); // something smart here
        cache.insert(key, r.clone());
        return r;
    }
}
```